# Writing a query to combine results from multiple tables with all possible combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name  char(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name char(50) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    uid INTEGER REFERENCES users (id) NOT NULL,
    pid INTEGER REFERENCES products (id) NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL CHECK (price >= 0)
);
```

I am trying to write a query that will give me all combinations of users and products, as well as the total amount spent by the user on that product. Specifically, if I have 5 products and 5 users, there should be 25 rows in the table. Right now I have a query that almost gets the job done, however, if the user has never purchased that product then there is no row printed at all.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
SELECT u.name as username, p.name as productname, SUM(o.quantity * o.price) as totalPrice
FROM users u, orders o, products p
WHERE u.id = o.uid
AND p.id = o.pid
GROUP BY u.name, p.name
ORDER BY u.name, p.name
```

I figure that this requires some sort of join, but my SQL knowledge is limited and I am not sure what would be the best way to go about doing this. I think if somebody can help me figure this out then I will have a much better understanding.

Comment: Your SQL dialect looks like Postgres, so I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: You need to create a CROSS JOIN and then LEFT JOIN the result with your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select u.name as username, p.name as productname,
       sum(o.quantity * o.price) as totalPrice
from users u cross join
     products p left join
     orders o
     on o.uid = u.id and o.pid = p.id
group by u.name, p.name;
```

The `cross join` generates all the rows.  The `left join` brings in the matching rows.  A simple rule when using SQL is:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @miladmaaan . . . You should ask that as another question.